# Vue.js: Binding two input to each other

Tags: vue.js

I'm currently starting on using vue.js, and have encountered a situation.

I wish to bind two inputs for example C = A - B. and B = A - C, where A is constant and a change in B or C will affect the other.

I successfully bind C using v-model and placing it in computed. However, when I tried the same for B, it ran into an infinite loop.

This should be something very simple however, I can't seem to find a solution to it.
Any help is appreciated thank you!

Edit: Code is included below. I wish for use the be able to key into either down_payment or loan_amount. After which it will calculate the other value automatically. However this way seems to make it go into a infinite loop

```
<input type="number" v-model="down_payment" class="form-control-right" placeholder="Downpayment" value="{{ down_payment }}" number>
<input type="number" v-model="loan_amount" placeholder="Loan Amount" value="{{loan_amount }}" number>
```

My javascript

```
 new Vue({
    el: '#calculator',
    data: {
        asking_price: 60000,
    },
    computed: {
        loan_amount: function(){
            return this.asking_price - this.downpayment;
        },
        down_payment : function(){
            return this.asking_price - this.loan_amount;
        },
    }
 });
```

Comment: Please post some code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really have two independent variables and one that is computed but needs to be writable and handle the dependencies in its setter.

```
   data: {
     asking_price: 60000,
     down_payment: 20
   },
   computed: {
     loan_amount: {
       get: function() {
         return this.asking_price - this.down_payment;
       },
       set: function(newValue) {
         this.down_payment = this.asking_price - newValue;
       }
     }
   }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t32926k6/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning vue myself, but I'm wondering if it would be better to just define `b` and `c` as data properties and then use a `watch` to recompute one or the other when there's a change (instead of using computeds).  Something like this:

```
        var vm = new Vue({
          el: '#calculator',
          data: {
            a: 10,
            b: 0,
            c: 10
          },
          watch: {
            'b' : function(newVal, oldVal) {
                this.c = this.a - newVal;
            },
            'c' : function(newVal, oldVal) {
                this.b = this.a - newVal;
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried but it does not seem to work.